# How can I do a Dropdown list with data from a model?

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I used  the modelchoicefield but this return a pk in string format so when I want to save it I have an error because in my model the format fields is integer.

I have this in my template

```
<select name="name_ id_perfil" >
<option value="Z">Select a brand</option>
{% for nombres in names %}
<option value="{{ nombres.id_perfil}}">{{ nombres.nombre }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

In my model i have this query

```
names = Perfil.objects.filter(status='1')
```

But it don't show nothing

[The Dropdown Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viCmo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try this

```
<option value={{ nombres.id_perfil}}>{{ nombres.nombre }}</option>
```